# `io:fileReadCsv` gives cannot be cast to class `CCE` exception

Tags: ballerina

Check the following code:

```
string[][] readCsv = check io:fileReadCsv(inputCSV);
```

it gives,

```
error: java.lang.ClassCastException {"message":"class io.ballerina.runtime.internal.values.ErrorValue cannot be cast to class io.ballerina.runtime.api.values.BObject (io.ballerina.runtime.internal.values.ErrorValue and io.ballerina.runtime.api.values.BObject are in unnamed module of loader 'app')"}
        at ballerina.io.1:fileReadCsv(file_csv_io.bal:30)
           balHack.problem_1_2.1:main(main.bal:9)
exception.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be happening when the input CSV path is incorrect.